# Raspberry Webiopi GPIO one time Email Trigger

Tags: python, email, triggers, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to make this code I have to only email once after the Door pin has been tripped. I am newish to python and have been reading the posts with similar question and trying what I have seen to my Script. But can't seem to get it to only send the email one time.

```
enter code here
import webiopi
import datetime
import smtplib
import subprocess
import os
GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

ARM = 7 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering
FLASH = 8
START = 25 # relay
DOOR = 11


HOUR_ON  = 8  # Turn Light ON at 08:00
HOUR_OFF = 18 # Turn Light OFF at 18:00



def setup():
    GPIO.setFunction(ARM, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(FLASH, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(START, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(DOOR, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # test if we are between ON time and tun the light ON
    if ((now.hour >= HOUR_ON) and (now.hour < HOUR_OFF)):
        GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.HIGH)


def loop():

    # retrieve current datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # toggle light ON all days at the correct time
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_ON) and (now.minute == 0) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.LOW):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.HIGH)

    # toggle light OFF
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_OFF) and (now.minute == 0) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.HIGH):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.LOW)


    if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.HIGH):
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.HIGH)
        webiopi.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.LOW)

    if (GPIO.digitalRead(DOOR) == GPIO.HIGH):
        SendText()

    # gives CPU some time before looping again
    webiopi.sleep(1)




def SendText():
    os.system("python /home/pi/html/myemail.py")






# destroy function is called at WebIOPi shutdown
def destroy():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(START, GPIO.LOW)



@webiopi.macro
def getLightHours():
    return "%d;%d" % (HOUR_ON, HOUR_OFF)

@webiopi.macro
def setLightHours(on, off):
    global HOUR_ON, HOUR_OFF
    HOUR_ON = int(on)
    HOUR_OFF = int(off)
    return getLightHours()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable, send_email, to track if it is time to send an email and if that email has been sent.

Create a global variable, send_email = False, because the variable will go inside the loop method and needs to be initialized.

Add to the SendText() if statement   and send_email

After the SendText() line set send_email = False

Add another if statement to check if GPIO.LOW and change the send_email to True

I have made the suggested changes to your code. I put * around all the text I added. Make sure to remove all the * from the code for it to work.

```
import webiopi
import datetime
import smtplib
import subprocess
import os
GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

ARM = 7 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering
FLASH = 8
START = 25 # relay
DOOR = 11


HOUR_ON  = 8  # Turn Light ON at 08:00
HOUR_OFF = 18 # Turn Light OFF at 18:00


*send_email = False*
def setup():
    GPIO.setFunction(ARM, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(FLASH, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setFunction(START, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(DOOR, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # test if we are between ON time and tun the light ON
    if ((now.hour >= HOUR_ON) and (now.hour < HOUR_OFF)):
        GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.HIGH)


def loop():

    # retrieve current datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # toggle light ON all days at the correct time
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_ON) and (now.minute == 0) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.LOW):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.HIGH)

    # toggle light OFF
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_OFF) and (now.minute == 0) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.HIGH):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.LOW)

    if (GPIO.digitalRead(ARM) == GPIO.HIGH):
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.HIGH)
        webiopi.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.digitalWrite(FLASH, GPIO.LOW)

    if (GPIO.digitalRead(DOOR) == GPIO.HIGH) *and send_email*:
        SendText()
        *send_email = False*

    *if (GPIO.digitalRead(DOOR) == GPIO.LOW) and not send_email*:
        *send_email = True*

    # gives CPU some time before looping again
    webiopi.sleep(1)




def SendText():
    os.system("python /home/pi/html/myemail.py")






# destroy function is called at WebIOPi shutdown
def destroy():
    GPIO.digitalWrite(ARM, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(START, GPIO.LOW)



@webiopi.macro
def getLightHours():
    return "%d;%d" % (HOUR_ON, HOUR_OFF)

@webiopi.macro
def setLightHours(on, off):
    global HOUR_ON, HOUR_OFF
    HOUR_ON = int(on)
    HOUR_OFF = int(off)
    return getLightHours()
```

Comment: I believe this may cause an UnboundLocalError because send_email will not be defined in the scope of loop():  You'll need to put in "global send_email" at the top of loop() function.